# Get the latest entered word in textbox Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, regex, string, windows-phone-8, textbox

I am developing one Windows phone app. In my app I want to get the latest entered word in textbox not the last word. And I want to change that latest entered word on space key pressed. I am getting the last word on a key up event like this:

```
private async void mytxt_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        { 
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_string) == false)
              {
                  string[] last_words = Regex.Split(textBox_string, @"\s+");
                  int i = last_words.Count();
                  last_words = last_words.Where(x => x != last_words[i-1]).ToArray();               last_word = last_words[last_words.Count() - 1];
                  last_word = last_word.TrimStart();
               }
         }
}
```

I am getting the last word by this method but actually I want to get latest entered word by user. Meaning, if the user moves the cursor directly to the middle of textbox and types any word then I want to get that word on space key pressed event; I want the position of that word and can change that word programmatically and update textbox.
For example, if the user types

> H!! my name vanani

but then the user moves the cursor directly after 'name' and types 'is sohan'

> H!! my name is sohan

then I want to get word and position of 'is' and same for 'sohan' in key up event of textbox. I need the position to replace that word with another word and update textbox with the new replaced text.

I have seen these questions. [winforms - get last word..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320521/get-last-entered-word-of-richtextbox-using-c-sharp) and [C# how to get latest char..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939200/how-to-get-the-latest-char-written-in-textbox) but they didn't help me. Please help me.

Comment: Try position = Regex.Match(text, @"\S*(?=\s$)").Index

Comment: after checking Regex.IsMatch(text, same pattern)

Comment: i cant understand. did you mean index by SelectionStart  of textbox???

Comment: You could get the word itself by Regex.Match(..).value too

Comment: yeah the starting index...

Comment: oh can you please give me a code for getting word and position of that word please..

Comment: see comment on answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73279/discussion-between-sohan-vanani-and-florian-schmidinger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded answer to my question.
Here is code worked for me.

```
Bool isFirst = false;
int mytempindex;
 private async void mytxt_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
      if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space)
        {
          int i = mytxt.SelectionStart;
          if (i < mytxt.Text.Length)
          {
            if (isfirst == false)
             { 
                mytempindex = mytxt.SelectionStart;
                isfirst = true;
             }
            else
             {
                int mycurrent_index = mytxt.SelectionStart;
                        int templength_index = mycurrent_index - mytempindex;
                string word = mytxt.Text.Substring(mytempindex, templength_index); //It is the latest entered word.
               //work with your last word.
             }
          }
       }
   }
```

I don't think it work in all situation but through this you can get idea about how to get latest entered word from Textbox or RichTextbox.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox_string, @"\S*(?=\s?$)"))
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(textBox_string, @"\S*(?=\s?$)");
    string word = match.Value;
    int startingIndex = match.Index;
    int length = word.Length;
}
```

Comment: Hey!! it gives the last word I don't want to get last word I want edited word or added word in textbox on any place whether it Is at first , middle or last or anywhere in textbox I just want to replace added or edited word with another word.

Comment: @sohanvanani never mind ... gotta go to work now, ill figure this out later